# Use Laravel Eloquent joining

Tags: php, laravel, join, eloquent

Hello I want to retrieve only rows of quizzes that the student didn't take yet
When he completes a quiz the variable done in QuizStudent table is going to become 1 
[image]

Quiz table

My relationships:
Quiz Modal:

```
 public function quizstudents(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Quizstudent');

    }
```

QuizStudent Modal:

```
  public function quiz(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Quiz','quiz_id');

    }
```

I tried to do it using Query Builder It's working

```
 $idUser = Auth::User()->id;
        $quizs= DB::table('quizzes')
       ->join('quizstudents', 'quizzes.id', '=', 'quizstudents.quizze_id')
       ->select('quizzes.id')
       ->where([['quizstudents.student_id','=',$idUser],['quizstudents.done','=','0']])

       ->distinct()
        ->get();
```

but the problem is that I get the error on my view

> Undefined property: stdClass::$classe

Because in view I use Eloquent style example: `$quiz->answer` and because I want to use paginate etc ..

So i tried to convert the QueryBuilder code above to eloquent I tried this:

```
   $quizs= Quiz::with('quizstudents')->whereIn('classe_id', $classes)->where([['quizstudents.student_id','=',$idUser],['quizstudents.done','=','0']])->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(10);
```

But I get the error

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'quizstudents.student_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `quizzes` where `classe_id` in (1) and (`quizstudents`.`student_id` = 79 and `quizstudents`.`done` = 0))
```

Thank you for your time and sorry in advance

> Edit: The two answers in bottom are amazing they are both working
>   thanks for the  people who helped, please don't miss the part to set
>   up your foreign key in the relationship if it's different than what's
>   normal  A little explanation I created the modal Quiz and the
>   migration and controller in the same time using modal:make Quiz -mc 
>   And didn't realise that the plural of quiz is quizzes so when I've set
>   the foreign key I thoughet about quizze_id will be the default but
>   Laravel is too smart and know that it should be quiz_id as default,
>   the luck on english can hurt you beware of this  And sorry for my bad
>   english

Comment: Typo? `quiztudents()` vs `quizstudents()`?

Comment: I fixed it but still nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not joining you Eloquent model, if you join would also get more rows than expected, you solve that by using distinct. An easy sub query solution, is to use `whereHas()` instead.

```
Quiz::with('quizstudents')
    ->whereIn('classe_id', $classes)
    ->whereHas('quizstudents', function ($query) use ($idUser) {
        $query->where('student_id', $idUser);
        $query->where('quizstudents.done', '0');
    })
    ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
    ->paginate(10);
```

This is not faster than joins, but achieves it fairly simple and for a start in my opinion is the way to go.

Comment: First thank you for your fast and amazing answer I never knew that we can do this using relationship I need to re-learn for sure  but I tried your code but I get "Call to undefined method App\Quiz::quizstudents()"
Did I miss something in your explanation?

Comment: just change quizstudents to  quiztudents

Comment: @OMR thanks I fixed the typo but still this code didn't work I get the error 
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'quizstudents.quiz_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `quizzes` where `classe_id` in (1) and exists (select * from `quizstudents` where `quizzes`.`id` = `quizstudents`.`quiz_id` and `student_id` = 79 and `quizstudents`.`done` = 0))

Comment: It's like Im looking for quizstudents.quiz_id but in my quistudents table it's quizze_id why Im looking for quiz_id ?

Comment: Ok guys I missed to set the attribute on relationship Thank you a lot all of you :) 
public function quizstudents(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Quizstudent','quizze_id');

    }

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
$doneQuizes = Quizstudents::where('student_id', $idUser) - >get() ;
$quizzes = Quiz::whereNotIn('id', $doneQuizes->pluck('quiz_id')) - >paginate(20);
```

Not sure about your models.... But you get the idea.
I know the other answer is good... But why so much bloatware for a simple task.

Comment: Oh that's a nice one I have to work on helpers and a lot of things Im a beginer thank you

Comment: I will be back to up your answer when I get the possibility thank you